# Empty lines when issuing a couple of commands over ssh from a Makefile

Tags: shell, ssh, makefile

I have a (somewhat clumsy) system for building on and remote controlling of a server:

```
SSH = ssh -t me@server '$(1)'

SEPARATOR = \n\n\n

do_something:
    $(call SSH, $(CMD1); $(SEPARATOR); $(CMD2))
```

Between `$(CMD1)` and `$(CMD2)`, I'd like to see a visible separator on the console for better readability. As you see, I tried something pretty obvious, but it doesn't work as expected. No need for something that looks perfect.

I'm perfectly aware that there might be better approaches in general, but currently the system works, so I don't want to completely re-design it just because of minor things like the `$(SEPARATOR)`.

Comment: It does not work for me: `Makefile:6: *** unterminated call to function 'call': missing ')'.  Stop.`. After fixing that, one more: `Makefile:6: *** unterminated call to function 'call': missing ')'.  Stop.`.

Comment: @Jakuje: Seems that I deleted the bracket when simplyfing the example. And it might not work when copying directly from SO into your text editor, because of tab vs. blank space in front of $(call....). But obviously, it's not really intended as a working example but rather to give the idea what I'm trying to do ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... obviously just writing a "\n" escapes will not work for you. If you wish to have it written in your transcript, you need to print them, such as

```
$(call SSH, $(CMD1); printf "$(SEPARATOR)"; $(CMD2))
```